# Axios : The .then and the .catch does not run in an axios post function

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios

I have read this block of code multiple times but I could not find anything wrong with it. The .then() and the .catch() seemingly do not run despite the API post being a success.

```
  const handleLogin = () => {
    axios
      .post(
        'http://localhost:3000/login',
        {
          email: emailLogin,
          password: passwordLogin,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        },
      )
      .then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem('name', response.data.name)
        setCookies('access_token', response.data.accessToken, { path: '/' })
        if (emailLogin.includes('@admin-kd.com')) {
          return window.location.replace('http://localhost:5173/admin')
        } else {
          return window.location.replace('http://localhost:5173/')
        }
      })
  }

  <button onClick={handleLogin} type="button" value={'Login'} />
```

Console logging before the post and it correctly did so, but once I tried to console log inside the .then() or the .catch() it simply did not

Comment: There is no `.catch()` in your code

Answer (score 1):

=> Add Catch block and check the console for error info: (Meanwhile Please check network tab in the browser - API is successful or not)

Note: Using async and await when you need to wait for the API response is a good practice.

Sample Code:

**1) Code with Async and Await implementation with catch block**

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3000/login",
      {
        email: emailLogin,
        password: passwordLogin,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );

    localStorage.setItem("name", response.data.name);
    setCookies("access_token", response.data.accessToken, { path: "/" });

    if (emailLogin.includes("@admin-kd.com")) {
      window.location.replace("http://localhost:5173/admin");
    } else {
      window.location.replace("http://localhost:5173/");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

**2) IF you don't want to add Async and Await**

```
const handleLogin = () => {
  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:3000/login",
      {
        email: emailLogin,
        password: passwordLogin,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      localStorage.setItem("name", response.data.name);
      setCookies("access_token", response.data.accessToken, { path: "/" });

      if (emailLogin.includes("@admin-kd.com")) {
        return window.location.replace("http://localhost:5173/admin");
      } else {
        return window.location.replace("http://localhost:5173/");
      }
    })

    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Let me know, if you have doubts.